# Flexbox deixa as imagens redimensionadas

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo o esboço de um projeto e preciso colocar três imagens um uma "linha" só. Decidi usar o `display:flex` e o `space-around` para deixa-lás com um espaço entre elas, porém elas estão no tamanho fora do normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<header id="infos">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ELX7vcLVocE/Ubj2DSqw-1I/AAAAAAAACJs/rfJ2ZbWWbOs/s1600/5o.JPG" width="200"/>     
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ELX7vcLVocE/Ubj2DSqw-1I/AAAAAAAACJs/rfJ2ZbWWbOs/s1600/5o.JPG" width="200"/>
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ELX7vcLVocE/Ubj2DSqw-1I/AAAAAAAACJs/rfJ2ZbWWbOs/s1600/5o.JPG" width="200"/>                 
    </div>
</header>
```

e o CSS:

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

body{
    background-color:rgba(127,255,30, 1);
    font-size: 18px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#infos{
    max-width: 960px;
    padding: 3em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logos{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

queria que elas ficassem no seu tamanho normal

Comment: Aqui está no tamanho correto amigo, verifique se no seu css não tem alguma propriedade global afetando esses elementos

Comment: Defina o tamanho da imagem, no caso só é necessário o width, assim elas não serão distorcidas pelo flexbox.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode aplicar na imagem

```
align-self: flex-start;
```

Dessa forma o flex não vai distorcer.

Answer (score -3):

Aparentemente as imagens estão ficando assim pois estão em um tamanho inatural graças ao flexbox. Uma forma de resolver isso é usando `object-fit: cover` ou `object-fit: contain`.

Answer (score -3):

só mudei a parte do .CSS de

```
.logos {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

para

```
.logos {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Mas tanto faz, todos dois funcionam sem alterar a altura das imagem.

Coloquei seu código no https://jsfiddle.net/38cL1kow/1/ de uma olhada.

Talvez no seu .CSS completo possa existir alguma `Class` que esteja modificando a IMG.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).